# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Я хочу быть как Рапунцель. Или Спящая Красавица. Или Золушка! Только не Златовласка." - годы шли, волосы росли и постепенно к девушке пришло понимание того, что уснуть на долгие годы она не хочет, трудиться в поте лица она не желает, а вот ждать принца, верить и мечтать - это ей подходит.

Answer (score 3):

> Я хочу быть как Рапунцель. Или Спящая Красавица. Или Золушка! Только
>   не Златовласка." - годы шли, волосы росли и постепенно к девушке
>   пришло понимание того, что уснуть на долгие годы она не хочет,
>   трудиться в поте лица она не желает, а вот ждать принца, верить и
>   мечтать - это ей подходит.

Нужна запятая перед "и постепенно". Плюс, по-моему, "Годы шли" нужно начать с нового абзаца.

ВАРИАНТ:

*"Я хочу быть как Рапунцель. Или Спящая Красавица. Или Золушка. Только не Златовласка!"*

*Годы шли, волосы росли, и постепенно к девушке пришло понимание того, что уснуть на долгие годы она не хочет, трудиться в поте лица она не желает, а вот ждать принца, верить и мечтать - это ей подходит.*

Answer (score 1):

А если оформить без кавычек, как несобственно-прямую речь:

Я хочу быть как Рапунцель. Или Спящая Красавица. Или Золушка! Только не Златовласка. Годы шли, волосы росли, и постепенно к девушке пришло понимание того, что уснуть на долгие годы она не хочет, трудиться в поте лица (она) не желает, а вот ждать принца, верить и мечтать - это ей подходит.